# Get values of model A using M2O relationship in model B in Odoo

Tags: model, view, relationship, odoo

I have 2 models `employee`. `employee` has the columns `emp_name` and `emp_pnum`.

I have a Many2One relationship between `employee` and `res_users` as shown in the codes.

```
class Employee(models.Model):
_name = "employee"
emp_name = fields.Char(string='Employee name')
emp_pnum = fields.Char(string='Phone number')
user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', string='user id', default=lambda self: self.env.uid, required = True)
```

In my form view, I wish to display the fields in the `res.users` model in the form view alongside the `employee` model's fields.

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="employee_tree">
        <field name="name">employee.tree</field>
        <field name="model">employee</field>
        <field name="priority" eval="8" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Employee">
                <field name="user_id" readonly="1"/>
                <field name="emp_name"/>
                <field name="emp_pnum"/>

//// I want to add the field values from the res.users table
//// through the Many2One relationship here

            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this logic in your code :

Model A:

```
model_A1 = fields.Char()
model_desc = fields.Char()
```

Model B:

```
model_A1_child = fields.Many2one('modelA')
model_A1_desc = fields.Char(related='model_A1_child.model_desc')
```

Comment: To add: in OP's example model A is `res.users` and model B is `employee`.